# Создание моделей с данными из файла json

Tags: json, extjs

Добрый день. Имеется файл формата json:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "users": [{
        "userID": 1,
        "name": "Вася",
        "surname": "Иванов",
        "date": '10/08/1991',
        "email": 'vasiv@mail.ru',
        "married": false
    }, {
        "userID": 2,
        "name": "Петя",
        "surname": "Федоров",
        "date": '03/08/1993',
        "email": 'petfed@yandex.ru',
        "married": true
    }, {
        "userID": 3,
        "name": "Вова",
        "surname": "Кузнецов",
        "date": '11/07/1989',
        "email": 'vok@mail.ru',
        "married": false
    }, {
        "userID": 4,
        "name": "Саша",
        "surname": "Сидоров",
        "date": '05/08/1991',
        "email": 'vvvs@mail.ru',
        "married": true
    }]
}
```

Ну и, соответственно, модель:

```
  Ext.define('User', {
           extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

            idProperty: 'userID',

            fields: [{
                name: 'userID',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'surname',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'date',
                type: 'date'
            }, {
                name: 'email',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'married',
                type: 'bool'
            }]
      });
```

**Вопрос: как мне создать 4 отдельных объекта моей модели с данными из вышеизложенного файла?**

**update:**
Я пробовал сохранять данные в хранилище (store), но не знаю, как выводить отдельные свойства для разных пользователей.